# Programming Theory - Proving Invariants

Tags: math, set, theory, set-theory

I have defined this pseudo-code for recognising strings using a relaxed-trie where the function Next[u,x] gives the set of nodes with u-edges from u ( basically the set of nodes such that (u,x,v) is an edge in T).

Here it is:

```
U := {1};

while s ≠ λ and U ≠ Ø do


 U:= U in u Union Next [u, head(s)];
 s:= tail(s)
 od;

 if U ≠ Ø then
  if Final[u] for some u in U then
    Accept 
  else reject
  fi
 else
   reject
 fi
```

Basically I have defined a postcondition for the loop, and given a loop invariant ( I think I have these elements covered, but if you think it will help to explain it go for it).

So I need to give a short argument stating why the invariant is invariant, (ie how it is preserved by the loop body, when the loop condition holds).

I then need to extend this pseudocode such that it can move to a new node without advancing the input :

(I think I would do this by adding another array (say Null) where Null[u] is the set of states it can move to from u without advancing the input)

It should also be changed such that each iteration before looking at the input all states can be reached from a state in U without advancing the input.

Thanks for all your help, am finding these two steps quite difficult, but think my psuedo-code for the first part is fine

Comment: Homework? If so, tag accordingly.

Comment: `I need to give a short argument` is a strange requirement for a software project

Comment: If you want us to help you with the invariant, it would be nice to know the invariant you defined...

Comment: As Eran says, please state all your logical assertions in the code.